# non-invertible matrix $A$ as a sequence of invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to show that for some non-invertible matrix $A$ with norm $\leq 1$ there exists a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of invertible matrices with limit equal to $A.$

I am pretty sure I did this a few years ago - using eigenvalues but I really cannot remember!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $1/n \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A_n = A + \frac 1n I$. Then 
$$
A_n X = 0 \iff AX = -\frac 1n X
$$
which implies $X=0$ as soon as $n > \frac 1{\sup Mod Ei(A)}$ where $ModEi(A)$ is the set of modules of eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Cool thanks! Is there any way of doing this with eigenvalues or was I just wrong haha?

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: why does it imply that $X=0$ as soon as $n > 1/\sup(E_i)$??

Comment: the "modules of" part was missing. The point is, there are a finite number of eigenvalues. So close to 0, only 0 is an eigenvalue.